# javascript split() array contains

Tags: javascript, regex, string

While learning JavaScript, I did not get why the output when we print the array returned of the Sting.split() method (with regular expression as an argument) is as explained below.

```
var colorString = "red,blue,green,yellow";
var colors = colorString.split(/[^\,]+/);
document.write(colors); //this print 7 times comma: ,,,,,,,
```

However when I print individual element of the array colors, it prints an empty string, three commas and an empty string:

```
 document.write(colors[0]);  //empty string
 document.write(colors[1]);  //,
 document.write(colors[2]);  //,
 document.write(colors[3]);  //,
 document.write(colors[4]);  //empty string
 document.write(colors[5]);  //undefined
 document.write(colors[6]);  //undefined
```

Then, why printing the array directly gives seven commas.

Though I think its correct to have three commas in the second output, I did not get why there is a starting (at index 0) and ending empty string (at index 4).

Please explain I am screwed up here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/[^\,]+/` splits on one or more characters that are **not** a comma. Thus, JavaScript will split your string on `red`, `blue` etc. The resulting leftovers, then, are the empty string at the beginning (the substring from index 0 to 0), the commas, and the empty string at the end. If you go out of bounds of the array you get `undefined` (as with any array).

```
red,blue,green,yellow
xxx xxxx xxxxx xxxxxx   <-- x is what is being eaten during split, because it's the delimiter
```

You just want `.split(",")`, which splits on commas, so that the commas are eaten and you are left with the colors.

Now, when you do `document.write(someArray)`, the array is converted into a string so that it can be displayed. This effectively means `someArray.join()` is called, which by default puts commas in between. So you get commas joined by commas, resulting in even more commas.

Answer (score 5):

When you print out the array, the different elements of the array are also separated by commas. So your output are these 5 array elements:

```
[empty string],[comma],[comma],[comma],[empty string]
```

Amounting to 7 commas. The reason why you get commas and empty strings instead of colors is, that `split` will split at everything that matches (instead of giving you back everything that matches). So simply don't use regular expressions at all, but just split at `,`:

```
var colors = colorString.split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

[^\,] <- this means anything **BUT** commas.

try
 `var colors = colorString.split(',');`